# kendo angular 2 grid styles

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using kendo-grid for angular2, we have our own UX Guidelines on how grid should be displayed. So how to implement this.

1) Do I need to depend on default theme for creating my own styles. Can I create my own styles and apply them directly to rows, header and group name

2) We are not using scss or webpack in our project in that case how to create styles specific for grid? I don't want all.css.

The link given below have not helped me enough to understand on applying custom styles
http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using SCSS or webpack, your best option is to [use the build process of the theme](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/#toc-use-the-build-process-of-the-theme) to compile it. You can change the variables in `scss/_variables.scss` and compile the theme with `COMPONENTS='grid' npm run build`. This will output the styles (for the grid only) in `dist/custom.css`

Comment: hi, do you think you can answer this question?  thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464601/angular-kendo-grid-change-background-color-of-pager